# How to display image in mail after deleted in app server?

Tags: java, image, email

I have code which creates an image in an application server and that image has been referred in mail html. After sending mail, image will be deleted in application server. When I open the mail, the image is not getting displayed in the mail.

I think my code is deleting the image before it is copied to the mail server. I have checked by deleting the image manually.

First I opened the mail (this time image gets copied to mail server) and then deleted the image in application server. When I open the mail 2nd time, image gets display (because image is in mail server I guess).

Again I ran the code, this time before opening mail first time. I deleted the image in the application server and opened the mail. Image is not displaying (because image not getting copied to mail server).

I cannot add the image as an attachment, as per my requirement.

Comment: Are you attaching the email or linking to it.  Check the source of the email you are receiving, if it has something like  <img src="cid:image"> then you are attempting to attach it and should be fine to delete the image.  Errors would occur if you are deleting the file before it is attached (as mentioned),or not correctly attaching the image to the message.

If it has something like <img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg"> then you're linking to it, and removing it from the server will cause the issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't attach the image then you have to ensure than whatever external img src is being referred to (e.g. `<img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg"/>`) remains accessible as long as people could reasonably view the message.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is referred to in the mail as an external http resource, then it will be visible as long as it is available on the server.

You can, indeed, attach the image to avoid this problem, but those are the only to options I know.

Comment: Tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailAttachments

Comment: And below on the same page is exactely what you want to do:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#IncludingImagesWithHTML

Answer (score 0):

You say that the image is "referred to" in your mail?

The img tag will contain a link (src) to you image.  Your image must be at this location when the mail is viewed.

If you're deleting the image from this location then obviously it can't be displayed.

Comment: Yeah but when i delete the image after opened mail first time and it getting display in the mail when i open second time. It shouldn't display as per view rite?

Comment: If it's a link, then every time you open the mail it'll try to download it from the location specified in the src part of the img tag.  So if you've deleted it then it won't display.  (Unless it's cached on the client side, but when the cache is cleared then it'll stop displaying)